# Query from multiple category (and)

Tags: categories, query

here is the request : get all post from category=11 (get 21 post), and then in the 21 post got from this category, refilter it, and show only post from category=10. So the request should be : cat=11&10. i what post that are from BOTH category at the same time, because my category are job and active. i what the listing of all the job, and then show just the one that are ative in the system !

```
$$mycat = "11&10" 
$showPostsInCategory->query('cat='. $mycat.'&posts_per_page=-1');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked up the [WP Codex on WP_Query for categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)?

They provide an example here. Also your category variable should probably only have one `$`. The way you've written your custom query also looks wrong, are you using WP_Query?

`$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__and' => array( 2, 6 ) ) );`

Answer (score 0):

for what it worth.. this is the final working code

```
$categories = "11&10";
$showPostsInCategory->query('category__and='. $categories.'&posts_per_page=-1');
```

Comment: Please explain your code, rather than just post it.